# internet explorer 8 didn't encode the character, how can I do?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, encoding, xmlhttprequest

I made a XHR get request to my server side, but the request url contains some Chinese characters, now in non-IE browser, it works well, but I found that under IE8, the characters won't be encoded automatically, server side can't handle the datas. how can I fix this issue?

I checked some posts related url encode/decode. I know before I make a request, I should encode the characters firstly, use:

```
   encodeURIComponent   
   decodeURIComponent
```

but I am confused that, in other browsers, they will encode the charactors automatically,
if I encode them manuully, in other browsers, they will be encoded twice? or not?
 if twice, how the server side handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't be encoded twice, the browser will check the character which is    reserved/unreserved. then to encode that automatically,
you can refer to [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)